# Asymptotic evaluation of summation (result is known in physics literature)

Tags: summation, asymptotics

I want to asymptotically evaluate
$$I = \frac{2\pi}{L} \sum_{q\in \frac{2\pi}{L} \mathbb Z - \{0\}} \frac1q \frac{e^{aq}}{e^{\beta q}-1} e^{-iqx} $$
as $L\to\infty$, where $0<a<\beta$ and $x\in\mathbb R$. Note that the summation gets singular near $q\neq 0$, but decays exponentially as $|q|\to\infty$ due to the factor $\frac{e^{aq}}{e^{\beta q}-1}$.

In a physics literature, $I$ is naively evaluated by taking the continuum limit
$$\frac{2\pi}{L} \sum_q \to P\int_{-\infty}^\infty dq, \tag{1}$$
with the prescription that the integral is understood as the principal-value sense. It is argued that the ad hoc method (1) modifies $I$ by a constant $C$. Then, the integral is evaluated using the residue theorem. The constant $C$ is finally obtained by considering the special case $x=0$.

The physics literature obtains the answer
$$I \approx -\log\left( -i \frac{2\beta}{L} \sinh \left( \frac\pi\beta (x+ia) \right)\right), \quad L\to\infty.$$

Question: Can I evaluate $I$ using other methods, or alternatively justify the physics literature argument rigorously?